# I need to do multiple file uploads in my ASP.NET page. I also have to display a progess bar with status of the file transfer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, progress-bar

I need to do multiple file uploads in my ASP.NET page. I also have to display a progress bar with the status of the file transfer. It should display an all file progress status bar separately and a total in a separate progress bar until the file upload has finished.

Comment: I wish I had "edit" privileges just so that I could go in and fix the spelling and grammatical errors in this question. It's otherwise solid, and doesn't look to be a dupe.

Comment: Ya i am not good in english...its my first day..i will improve my self...

y this site not providing spell checker in this text area????

Comment: Have you ever tried pasting code or anything technical into Microsoft Word? You'd understand why. Firefox has built-in spell checking of form fields.

Comment: @Josh - Is your Gravatar supposed to be the guy from "Little Monsters" after the evil guy breaks his horn off? http://content8.flixster.com/question/43/19/32/4319326_std.jpg

Comment: @Pat: done. It needs a review, though. You may suggest.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Thanks, reads a lot better now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try Uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

It's a very nice free JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You could use any of the following:

**Flash based**

- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify) (jQuery plugin)
- [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/)
- [Flajaxian](http://flajaxian.com/) (integrates with ASP.NET)

**Non-flash, ASP.NET based solutions**

- [NeatUpload](http://www.brettle.com/neatupload)
- [ASP.NET File Upload Module](http://darrenjohnstone.net/category/aspnet-file-uploads/)

These are all free, support multiple file uploads and progress bars, and are relatively easy to integrate.

I've personally used Uploadify and NeatUpload, though I had some [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239881/inaccurate-progress-bar-when-uploading-large-files-using-asp-net-and-uploadify) getting Uploadify to display the progress bar correctly (which I later found out was due to my anti-virus software, thanks to StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Telerik Upload Component](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/upload.aspx) ([demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/upload/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)). (It does cost money, but it is worth it if you need functionality like this.